# How to use \ifx and \@currenvir?

Tags: environments, tex-core, conditionals

### Description

Hi, I was trying to make a simple \ifx statement to decide whether something was inside and environment and execute commands accordingly.

I want the notes in my document to be raggedright and in sans-serif. But, for a more consistent look, I also want them to be indented if outside an environment (mainly for descriptions, itemizes and enumerates) but to have no indentation if set inside one.

### The code

So I tried the following simple code using `\ifx` and the `@currenvir` macro.

```
% Saving the \parindent value for later use
\newlength{\savedparindent}
\setlength{\savedparindent}{\parindent}
% Assigning the value 'document' to a control sequence for comparing later.
% I did this after noticing that outside any environment the \@currenvir macro would
% print the value 'document'
\newcommand*{\docname}{document}
% The actual \ifx conditional. The \Nota command (for note in spanish) is meant
% to be used in the document to add notes formatted in a distinctive way.
\newcommand{\Nota}[1]{
\begingroup
\makeatletter
\ifx\@currenvir\docname
    \raggedright\setlength{\parindent}{\savedparindent}\sffamily
    \else
    \raggedright\sffamily
   \fi  
\makeatother
#1
\endgroup
\par
}
```

### The problem

In all my testing, the `else` part gets executed inside and environment and also outside, in 'normal' running text. Any ideas as to why it's not working? (Sorry if the solution is obvious, I have no experience in either programming or TeX witchcraft).

Don't know if this is relevant, but that code was tested compiling with luatex.

### The solution

The `\docname` had to be defined after `\makeatletter`, also `\par` needs to be inside the group to work correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `\newcommand*` (or `\def`) to define `\docname` so that it is not `\long`. A `\long` macro is never `\ifx` equal to a non-long one, even if they have the same replacement text.

Also

```
\makeatletter
```

has to be before the definition, having it inside any command is like having `\verb` inside a command it does not work as the input has already been tokenized.

and finally you need `\par` before the `\endgroup` as `{\raggedright zzz}` has no effect unless there is a paragraph break before the `}`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response, had no idea about ```\long```. After adding the fix you suggested the command still behaves erroneously: it sets the text without indentation (that is, the else statement) regardless of the environment. I'll edit the question to include the fix, and work on making a MWE that will also be added to the question.

Comment: @JLanzuisi oh just spotted another error

Comment: Wonderful, now it all works as intended, thanks